# Не появляется dataGridViewComboboxCell

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма. На ней dataGridView. В ней есть столбец с названием "Формат". При двойном клике на ячейку этого столбца я создаю dataGridViewComboboxCell, но он не появляется сразу, а появляется при клике по другой ячейке. Как это иcправить?

```
  DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   cell.Items.Add(hex);
   cell.Items.Add(dec);
   dt.Rows[e.RowsIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;
```

Comment: Приложите Ваш код

Comment: @Sv__t Сделал. Это код срабатывает при двойном клике по ячейке.

Comment: код на событии `CellClick` висит?

Comment: @ Sv_t На DoubleСlick

Comment: да, ошибся. У меня на событии `CellDoubleClick` все работает как нужно.

Comment: А если добавить `dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Не помогает.

Comment: @Sv_t  А в чем тогда у меня ошибка.